# Reading byte array and converting into float in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, hex

I know there are many questions related to it but still they are not solving my problem. Below is my byte array:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see that the byte is of `28` and each `4-byte` value represents a single value i.e. I have a client machine which sent me `2.4` and while reading it, it is then converted into bytes.

```
//serial port settings and opening it
        var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

        serialPort.Open();

        var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
        stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        // send request and waiting for response
        // the request needs: slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount            
        var responseBytes = stream.RequestFunc3(slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount);

        // extract the content part (the most important in the response)
        var data = responseBytes.ToResponseFunc3().Data;
```

**What I want to do?**

1. Convert each 4 byte one by one to hex, save them In a separate variable. Like 
   `hex 1 = byte[0], hex2 = byte[1], hex3 = byte[2], hex4 = byte[3]
   ..... hex28 = byte[27]`
2. Combine 4-byte hex value and then convert them into float and assign them a variable to hold floating value. Like 
   `v1 = Tofloat(hex1,hex2,hex3,hex4);` // assuming ToFloat() is a function.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `var bytes = new byte[] { 64, 25, 153, 154 }.Reverse().ToArray(); float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);`?

Comment: @Jimi, why is the call to `.Reverse()` necessary?

Comment: @simon-pearson Different endianness. The source is BigEndian (or just sent that way, it can be part of the protocol, it's usually documented). Of course, you can check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to test the endianness of the current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the first value is 2.4 and each float is represented by 4 bytes;

```
byte[] data = { 64, 25, 153, 154, 66, 157, 20, 123, 66, 221, 174, 20, 65, 204, 0, 0, 65, 163, 51, 51, 66, 95, 51, 51, 69, 10, 232, 0 };
```

We can group the bytes into 4 byte blocks and reverse them and convert each part to float like:

```
int offset = 0;
float[] dataFloats =
    data.GroupBy(x => offset++ / 4) // group by 4. 0/4 = 0, 1/4 = 0, 2/4 = 0, 3/4 = 0 and 4/4 = 1 etc.
    // Need to reverse the bytes to make them evaluate to 2.4
    .Select(x => BitConverter.ToSingle(x.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray(), 0))
    .ToArray();
```

Now you have an array of 7 floats:

[image]